# Dynamic Python function parameter rerouting

Tags: python-3.x, function, dynamic, arguments

I have a python function

`func(a, b, c, d, e)`.

I want to pass this function to another function that evaluates it. The catch is that this other function only varies an arbitrary subset of the parameters `(a, b, c, d, e)`, and the other parameters shall be preloaded with a constant. The parameter order may also change.

For example: I would like `func_2` to vary a, c, and d, while b=3 and e=4. So I need a routine

```
def convert(func, variables=[3, 0, 2], constants=[1, 4], vals=[3, 4]):
    ...
    python magic
    ...
    return func_2
```

that converts:

`func(a, b, c, d, e)` -> `func_2(d, a, c, b=3, e=4)`,

so that when I call `func_2(1, 2, 3)`, what is actually called behind the scenes is `func(2, 3, 3, 1, 4)`.

(This is for an optimization algorithm that operates on subspaces of a parameter space, and these subspaces can change from cycle to cycle. `func` is a cost function.)

How do I code `convert` in Python 3?

Comment: Why do you need this function? Isn't it easier to write `func_2 = lambda d,a,c: func(a,3,c,d,4)` each time you need to "convert"?

Comment: For this example, this is exactly what I need, but the associations and values change in a loop. So I need to make the lambda expression dynamic. As I tried to express in my post, I define the variable and constant order as well as the constant values using lists. Depending on the optimization outcome of one iteration, the subspace I have to work in in the next iteration will change.

Comment: In that general case, you need to construct a list/tuple of arguments then use the spread syntax to pass those to the function.

Comment: what does `convert` return exactly? A callable function? A string?

Comment: A callable function.

Comment: @user202729: The function that I want to construct from the prototype is used many times in the function that I'm passing it to. I'd rather do the parameter acrobatics just once and pass a ready-to-use function rather than juggling parameters around several times later. Really no elegant solution for this? Maybe I just didn't understand your suggestion for the general case you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
def convert(func, vars, fixed):
    # vars: list of indices
    # fixed: dictionary mapping indices to constants
    n = len(vars) + len(fixed)
    def func_2(*args):
        newargs = [None] * n
        for i, j in enumerate(vars):
            newargs[j] = args[i]
        for k in fixed:
            newargs[k] = fixed[k]
        return func(*newargs)
    return func_2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a possible solution:

```
def convert(func, var, const, vals):
    def func2(*args):
        params = [args[var.index(i)] if i in var
                  else vals[const.index(i)]
                  for i in range(len(var)+len(const))]
        return func(*params)
    return func2
```

It works with any number of parameters